# How can hide legal link of the mkmapview monotouch iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mkmapview

MKMapview have legal link on its bottomright point. I want to add a button on this place. the button have some kind of transparency. can I hide the legal link?
Or if i set my buttons in a way that hide this link may apple reject my app?

I also have some kinds of subviews in my map view.

Comment: You can move it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201670/how-do-you-move-the-legal-sign-in-mapview  Not sure if you will be able to hide it.

Comment: Also changing its position is great for me. but i myself adds some kind of  subviews to my map and by code in above link i get this subviews.

Comment: Ow, I was wrong, i used index 0 and it was wrong. Thanks. Please leave your comment as a answer to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You SHOULD NOT hide this legal link or your app will be rejected by Apple.

**EDIT :** I've found a category wich allows you to move this link, I'm not the author : https://github.com/bartvandendriessche/MKMapView-AttributionView

Comment: can you add some link to prove your answer?

Comment: Sure, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205 OR http://rogchap.com/2011/06/17/mkmapview-moving-the-google-logo/

Comment: I see no reference to the legal annotation in the Apple docs. The second link is dead

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this one but i don't know apple will approve or not.

```
[[self.mapView.subviews objectAtIndex:1] removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 4):

Removing the label will probably lead to your app getting rejected. However it can be done like this with swift:

```
var legalLabel: UIView?
for subview in stableMapView.subviews {
    if String(describing: type(of: subview)) == "MKAttributionLabel" {
        legalLabel = subview
    }
}
legalLabel?.isHidden = true
```

Answer (score 0):

More safe version:

```
extension MKMapView {
    var attributedView: UIView? {
        for subview in subviews {
            if String(describing: type(of: subview)).contains("Label") {
                return subview
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func hideAttributedView() {
        guard let attributedView = attributedView else {
            return
        }
        attributedView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to hide the apple logo and legal text in the map (MapView).

To hide the apple logo in the map.

```
mapView.subviews[1].isHidden = true
```

To hide the legal text

```
mapView.subviews[2].isHidden = true
```