# MKMapSnapshotter removes "Legal" from snapshots

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkmapsnapshotter

I am using the `MKMapSnapshotter` to create a `UIImage` screenshot of a small `MKMapView` (and stored for later use). But one thing I have noticed is that it removes the "Legal" label from the  snapshot. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149395/how-can-hide-legal-link-of-the-mkmapview-monotouch-iphone) the answer states that removing the "Legal" is against Apple policy. Will this affect my submission to the app store ? Or is it just required in the maps, and not the screenshots ?

I have checked the bounds of the `MKMapView` and the snapshot rect. There is no difference, so there's no possibility of it being cropped.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a legal issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a legal issue.

Comment: OK. Do you suggest I delete the question, or leave it here closed?

Comment: I suggest deleting it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it's a legal issue.
The "Legal" label is actually a link (perhaps a UIButton?) pointing to a legal document.

The sole purpose of MKMapSnapshotter is to create images for a specified map region/rect. **The output is an image where the "legal" link would not serve any useful or legal purpose.**

Please also note that MKMapSnapshotter is an official Apple API, in other words it is Apple, not you, who actually removed the "Legal" label/link.

Answer (score 4):

First off, `MKMapSnapshotter` does not actually *remove* the (private) `MKAttributionLabel`, because by default it's not in the map image data.

You are not supposed to remove the `MKAttributionLabel` from an *interactive* `MKMapView`, since it leads you to the legal text (it's either a UIButton or a label that has a gesture recognizer applied to it).

MKMapSnapshotter hands out image data, it would not make sense to require embedding a button there.