# Reposition legal label ( MKAttributionLabel )

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, mkmapview, mapkit

I'd want to move the Legal label to the right side. On iOS 6 and 7 the below solution was working fine, however on iOS 8.3 it seems to not work.

I get the label, then with a timer (0.1 sec) in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` I call this method :

```
-(void)moveLegalLabel
{
    UIView * legalLink = [self attributionView];
    legalLink.frame = CGRectMake(self.mapView.frame.size.width - legalLink.frame.size.width - 10, self.mapView.frame.size.height - legalLink.frame.size.height - 10 , legalLink.frame.size.width, legalLink.frame.size.height);
    legalLink.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
}
```

which works nicely for rotation, etc.
But as soon as I scroll the map, the label jumps back to the left.
Tried to call this method in the `regionDidChangeAnimated` but the label jumps back first to the left then to right, it's really annoying...

How could I force that stupid label to stay on the right side ?

**Solution as suggested by Christian :**

1. Subclass the MKMapView
2. Move the `moveLegalLabel` code there
3. Call it in `layoutSubviews`

`-(void)layoutSubviews
 {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self moveLegalLabel];
 }`

Comment: Why on earth would you do that with a 0.1 delay?

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr Because I need to preserve the label on the right even after rotation. The main problem is the map repositions that label after each region change...

Comment: Then how about you hook into after the rotation (but without a delay!) and undo whatever the map did?

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr That's what I am doing, but as I said, that is working fine, with or without a delay. The problem is the map repositions that stupid label when I change the map's region ( scroll/zoom the map ). And the moveLegalLabel in`regionDidChangeAnimated` works randomly. Sometimes it keeps the label on right, sometimes not ...

Comment: That's because the hook you use to position it is wrong. Try subclassing the map and overriding `-layoutSubviews`.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr You are absolutley right. It indeed works this way. I thought I could avoid subclassing because calling `moveLegalLabel` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` should be called **after** each view's own `layoutSubviews`... Thank you really much.

Comment: Should I put this into an answer so you can accept it or will you accept one of the other answers?

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr Feel free to do so. I'd be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hooks like `-viewDidAppear:`, `-mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:` or `-mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:`, like others suggested, are not suited for this purpose.

You best bet would be to subclass `MKMapView` and layout your label in `-layoutSubviews` **after** calling `super`.

Answer (score 8):

You need it to be in viewDidAppear and both of the MKMapViewDelegate methods. If you don't put it in both delegate methods you will get the jumping that you saw. That's all!

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self moveLegalLabel];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self moveLegalLabel];
}
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self moveLegalLabel];
}

-(void)moveLegalLabel
{
    UIView * legalLink = [self.map.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
    legalLink.frame = CGRectMake(self.map.frame.size.width - legalLink.frame.size.width - 10, self.map.frame.size.height - legalLink.frame.size.height - 10 , legalLink.frame.size.width, legalLink.frame.size.height);
    legalLink.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
}
```

Comment: It's somewhat better, but it still jumps randomly... With `regionWillChangeAnimated` implemented, indeed, the label stays on the right side **while** I move the map, which is nice. But after that in `regionDidChangeAnimated` soemtimes works, sometimes randomly jumps back...

Comment: Hmmm im testing on iOS 8 on simulator and it's working fine. Are you repositioning the label anywhere else?

Comment: No ... I commented it even in `viewDidLoad` . What simulator do you have ? 8.3 ?

Comment: I tested on all simulators and a 8.3 device and the problem still exists. It works for like 30% of the cases.

Answer (score 5):

**A Swift 4 example:**

- Working on iOS 11
- No need for sub-classes

(based off of Erik's answer)

```
func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   moveLegalLabel()
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
   moveLegalLabel()
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
   moveLegalLabel()
}

func moveLegalLabel() {
   let legalLabel: UIView = mapView.subviews[1]
   legalLabel.frame=CGRect(x: mapView.frame.size.width - (legalLabel.frame.size.width ?? 0.0) - 10, y: mapView.frame.size.height - (legalLabel.frame.size.height ?? 0.0) - 10, width: legalLabel.frame.size.width ?? 0.0, height: legalLabel.frame.size.height ?? 0.0)
}
```

Comment: Works with iOS 13.6

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `transform` this way:

```
- (void)moveLegalLabel
{
    UIView *legalLink = [self attributionView];
    legalLink.transform = CGTransformMakeTranslation(self.mapView.frame.size.width - CGRectGetMaxX(legalLink.frame) - CGRectGetMinX(legalLink.frame), self.mapView.frame.size.height - CGRectGetMaxY(legalLink.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(legalLink.frame));
}
```

If not works try to use `layer.transform`:

```
- (void)moveLegalLabel
{
    UIView *legalLink = [self attributionView];
    legalLink.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(self.mapView.frame.size.width - CGRectGetMaxX(legalLink.frame) - CGRectGetMinX(legalLink.frame), self.mapView.frame.size.height - CGRectGetMaxY(legalLink.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(legalLink.frame));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must load your code in viewDidAppear, before it your code may not take place. Apparently your code was being compiled before the views were ready.

```
-(void)moveLegalLabel
{
    UIView * legalLink = _mapView.subviews[1];
    legalLink.frame = CGRectMake(self.mapView.frame.size.width - legalLink.frame.size.width - 10, self.mapView.frame.size.height - legalLink.frame.size.height - 10 , legalLink.frame.size.width, legalLink.frame.size.height);
    legalLink.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self moveLegalLabel];
}
```

If you create a button and put your code in its action, when you click you can see the label moving.

Answer (score 0):

Here I moved it from the bottom to the top:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    // Move legal notice since covered in design
    mapView.subviews
        .first { "\(type(of: $0))" == "MKAttributionLabel" }?
        .frame.origin.y = mapView.frame.minY + 10
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For solution this problem you can:

1.Create Subclass (MKMapView)

```
class CustomMapView: MKMapView {

}
```

2.Override layouSubviews like this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let legalLabel: UIView = self.subviews[1]
        let frame = .....
    }
```

*This way works for me*