# IOS UIMapView "legal" link clickable when outside of clip bounds?

Tags: ios, swift, android-mapview

I have a mapview that is being clipped into a circle by the following code.

```
    roundMapView.layer.cornerRadius = roundMapView.frame.size.width/2
    roundMapView.clipsToBounds = true
    roundMapView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
```

The problem I'm having is that outside of the circle, if I tap in the bottom left area, it will send me to the "legal" disclaimer that appears on the map. It seems the map's "Legal" link is clickable, even if it isn't inside the clipped circular mask.

Any way to stop this from happening? It is right next to a button on my UI and is really annoying when it is clicked accidentally.

EDIT: Uploaded two images: One is of the "legal" link I am talking about, the other shows a red dashed circle where the link is clickable even though it isn't in the clip bounds of the mapView.

http://s27.postimg.org/ustcejmcf/Screen_Shot_2015_06_30_at_7_21_51_PM.png

http://s27.postimg.org/f623168kf/Screen_Shot_2015_06_30_at_7_49_43_PM.png

Comment: He could not understand your question, but I happen to handpick, which put an invisible element that is above the object that you do not want.

Comment: I am not able to post a picture or I think my problem would be clearer - but thank you for the comment. The issue is I cannot be sure where this legal link is.. are you saying to put something like a label or empty button behind my button I want to be clickable?

Comment: You can upload images and add external links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: Not an answer to the question, but could be a serious reason to reconsider whole  approach and make question invalid.

You are trying to hide legal information from users. I believe it is something that Apple would try to avoid by all costs. I also would not suggest to do so, as it may have legal implications for developer as well as not pass Apple Review.

JFYI The way how Apple may avoided clipToBounds limitations described here — [interaction beyond bounds of uiview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432995/interaction-beyond-bounds-of-uiview)

What I would suggest is actually to move link as described here [How do you move the legal sign in mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201670/how-do-you-move-the-legal-sign-in-mapview)

Comment: Moving the legal text would also fix the problem - thank you for your reply. The main problem is a user going "what happened" when the legal text pops up. My intention isn't to remove the legal text, it is mainly to avoid confusion