# Moving apple maps apple logo "legal" text

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Is there a way to manipulate, move around the apple logo and "legal" text from the bottom of the mkmapview?

Kind of what google maps has.

[image: Image to see what I'm trying to move around]

Comment: Check out https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88631
Or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201670/how-do-you-move-the-legal-sign-in-mapview

Answer (score 13, accepted):

##### UIKit

You can change it by setting the `layoutMargins` of the `mapView`. For example, this will move it out from the bottom:

```
mapView.layoutMargins.bottom = -100 // removes the 'legal' text
mapView.layoutMargins.top = -100 // prevents unneeded misplacement of the camera
```

---

##### SwiftUI

You can add negative padding to the map and then clip it to appear normal like:

```
Map(){ }
    .padding(.vertical, -100)
    .clipped()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the mapView layoutMargins it will offset all the shown content in the map (centering on annotations and such).

If you want to only move the 2 items, I would suggest adding these Extensions:

```
extension MKMapView {

    var logoView: UIView? {
        for subview in subviews {
            if String.init(describing: subview).localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("MKAppleLogoImageView") {
                return subview
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    var legalView: UIView? {
        for subview in subviews {
            if String.init(describing: subview).localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("MKAttributionLabel") {
                return subview
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func moveLogoView(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
        logoView?.moveOrigin(x: x, y: y)
    }

    func moveLegalView(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
        legalView?.moveOrigin(x: x, y: y)
    }

}

extension UIView {

    func moveOrigin(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
        let originX = self.frame.origin.x
        let originY = self.frame.origin.y
        self.frame.origin = CGPointMake(originX + x, originY + y)
    }

}
```

Then, those can be used after the map was loaded. Works in viewDidLoad() with a DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter or didLayoutSubviews()

```
mapView.moveLogoView(x: -40, y: 60)
mapView.moveLegalView(x: 20, y: 60)
```